# Will constant overwrite of NSManagedObject attributes cause memory issues?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

```
        dailyItem.remainingTime =  @([dailyItem.remainingTime floatValue] - 1.0);
```

My project crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Above is the line where it breaks.

`dailyItem` is an NSManagedObject and `remainingTime` is one of its attributes. What I'm doing to `dailyItem` is basically changing this attribute with a timer that fires every second.

```
    countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(countdownForDailyItemTimer:)
                                                   userInfo:dailyItem
                                                    repeats:YES];
```

I schedule the timer to start counting and when it fires every second the method below gets called.

```
- (void)countdownForDailyItemTimer:(NSTimer *)timer{
    if([timer.userInfo isKindOfClass:[DailyItem class]]) {
        DailyItem *dailyItem = (DailyItem *)timer.userInfo;
        dailyItem.remainingTime =  @([dailyItem.remainingTime floatValue] - 1.0);
        NSLog(@"counting daily item remaining time: %@", dailyItem.remainingTime);

    }
}
```

Almost every time, a few minutes into the counting, the project crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
I want to know if it is the constant overwrite of the managed object that is causing the memory problem.

Thanks.

**update**:
In addition to overwriting attributes, I have multiple objects observing the `dailyItem`. Every time its `remainingTime` changes(i.e. every sec) they get notified and do some stuff.

## update2:

I found out somewhere else that EXC_BAD_ACCESS means I'm trying to send a message to a already released object instead of memory problem I had previously thought.

So I checked relevant things in my code and discovered that this is due to an unremoved observer. I have `addObserver: forKeyPath:` and `removeObserver: forKeyPath:` implemented in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidDisappear`, respectively, in a view controller that is embedded in a navigation controller. And when I swipe at the edge to navigate back in this VC but stop halfway and get back, `viewWillAppear gets called, the VC again is registered as an observer but never removed, the end result being the same VC is registered twice. I logged some information that might help explain this.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     .......
    [self.dailyItem addObserver:self
                 forKeyPath:COUNTDOWN_OBSERVING_KEYPATH
                    options:0
                    context:NULL];

}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    NSLog(@"self.dailyItem observation info when view did disappear:%@",     self.dailyItem.observationInfo);
    [self.dailyItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:COUNTDOWN_OBSERVING_KEYPATH];
    NSLog(@"self.dailyItem observation info after removal:%@", self.dailyItem.observationInfo);
}
```

This is the console output when I directly hit the back button on the navigation bar.

```
view did disappear
2014-08-03 19:49:26.645 Daily Plan[35491:13279953] self.dailyItem observation     info when view did disappear:<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7b939b40> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x79f3a140: Observer: 0x79f3c1d0, Key path: countingState, Options: <New:     YES, Old: YES, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x79f368f0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7b96b610: Observer: 0x79f3b570, Key path: remainingTime, Options: <New: NO,     Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7b937990>
)
2014-08-03 19:49:26.645 Daily Plan Without CocoaPods[35491:13279953] self.dailyItem observation     info after removal:<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x79f36470> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x79f3a140: Observer: 0x79f3c1d0, Key path: countingState, Options: <New:     YES, Old: YES, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x79f368f0>
)
```

This time I tried to swipe back but stopped halfway. After getting back to the VC, I hit the back button again.

```
view did disappear
2014-08-03 19:49:43.152 Daily Plan[35491:13279953] self.dailyItem observation     info when view did disappear:<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x79e18a90> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x79f3a140: Observer: 0x79f3c1d0, Key path: countingState, Options: <New:     YES, Old: YES, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x79f368f0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7b8675a0: Observer: 0x7b86c8d0, Key path: remainingTime, Options: <New: NO,     Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7b937990>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7b8675a0: Observer: 0x7b86c8d0, Key path: remainingTime, Options: <New: NO,     Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7b937990>
)
2014-08-03 19:49:43.152 Daily Plan [35491:13279953] self.dailyItem observation     info after removal:<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7b8675e0> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x79f3a140: Observer: 0x79f3c1d0, Key path: countingState, Options: <New:     YES, Old: YES, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x79f368f0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7b8675a0: Observer: 0x7b86c8d0, Key path: remainingTime, Options: <New: NO,     Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7b937990>
)
(lldb)
```

In the second scenario, when I hit the back button to get to another VC, the previous VC is only removed once but has been added twice, leaving it still observing(by which time it's already released from the memory).In the another VC, the timer(a global one) is still firing off every second, and the `remainingTime` of the `dailyItem` is still changing as well, but the method `observeValueForKeyPath: ofObject:` can't find the target, thus causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Having learning all this, I relocated the `addObserver` method in `viewDidLoad` and the problem is solved.

I learned two things in the process of looking for the reason:

1. `ViewWillDisappear` and `ViewWillAppear` are called when you swipe at the edge to navigate back but stop halfway.
2. I really love swiping around at the edge. That's why I had thought the EXC_BAD_ACCESS was due to the constant overwrite of NSManagedObject instead of my swipe, both happening only too frequently.

Comment: More code would be helpful.

Comment: Have you made sure that remainingTime is not nil when you are accessing its float value property?

Comment: Yes. As shown above, I log the remaining time each sec and before the crash it works as normal.

Comment: Is `dailyItem` guaranteed to be accessed and set on the same thread as `dailyItem`'s managed object context? If not, you should either write code that guarantees this or use a child context for the other thread.

Comment: `userInfo` should be a dictionary containing your managed object.

Comment: @duci9y Is this a convention or something? What's the advantage of making it a dictionary containing the object over just the object itself?